# I don't know how to connect between the site and my database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I'm using SQL server and web developer(C#).
I know I should do something with my connection string, but I don't exactly what and where I should do that.

Can you write me code example
or explain me what to do?

Edit:
I should connect my database with the site(the site is on the internet).
how would i know the right path for this database?
I should put his address, IP or what?

Comment: With out proper information no one can help please provide some more information

Answer (score 1):

first you have to know that you cannot just add the database to the server like this !!!

you have to script the whole database, and then you have to upload it into your database server like godaddy.com or what ever . your hosting server should support you with these setails ,they gonna give you a user name and password and other details so you can access to the sql manger ( like my ltitladmin) online ....there you have to upload or just copy and execute your code directly so you can make all your tables and stored procedures or what ever ....

after all this all what you have to is just take the online database new connection string and then add it o your web.confg or in you pages ,this is the way how to make it work right.

Answer (score 0):

### I guess you need to read about it a little:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ASP.NET application.

Basically, connection strings could be stored anywere.

One of suggested connection strings' store is Web.config file. Look for "connectionStrings" configuration element and you should find there the one to change for your production server.

Look at this page:
http://www.connectionstrings.com/

You'll find SQL Server connection string examples.

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot os ways to do that, try to take a look to this simple example:

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson02.aspx